# JQuery to Update Parent Class In External File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am having a bit of trouble when trying to move from having all my code in one file, to having it stored in three separate files (CSS, HTML, and JS). When they were all in one file, the jquery code that I was using was working (not perfectly, but thats a different issue) but it was working enough for what I needed it. So in an effort to organize things I began to move code into the different files, as opposed to one sloppy HTML file.

Everything works fine, except for the jQuery code which is in the Javscript file. I was using the hover() function so that when the link with class "ne" was hovered over, it would update the parent's (a screen overlay) background to now be a certain image.

But now that it is in an external file, I am not sure how I can achieve the same functionality.

Here is the snippet for the code I am currently workign with:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}

/*$(".ne").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("newengland");
});
$(".ne").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("overlay");
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("newengland");
});*/
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400');
body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}
.colorado{
  width:3840px; height:2160px; background:url('D:/Desktop/Background-Images/coneeu.jpg');
  background-position: 0 0px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.newengland{
  width:3840px; height:2160px; background:url('D:/Desktop/Background-Images/coneeu.jpg');
  background-position: 0 2160px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.europe{
  width:3840px; height:2160px; background:url('D:/Desktop/Background-Images/coneeu.jpg');
  background-position: 0 4320px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  font-family: Oswald;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#" class="co" onhover = "update()" >co</a>
    <a href="#" class="ne">ne</a>
    <a href="#" class="eu">eu</a>
    <a href="#" class="ab">ab</a>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Temp</h2>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Open</span>
</body>
</html>
```

And what I aim to have happen is when you hover over the different elements of the overlay, it should add a class to the div, which will change its background. And again, this was working in the spaghetti code file, but now it is not. Hope you can help, thank you for reading!

Comment: Why are you trying to dynamically add a script tag with jQuery through javascript?

Answer (score 0):

No need to dynamically import jQuery, just import it with a script tag in the html before your javascript file.

Also, make sure you are using [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to make sure your DOM is rendered before executing jQuery:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ne").hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("newengland");
    });
    $(".ne").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("overlay");
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("newengland");
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400');
body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}
.colorado{
  width:3840px; height:2160px; background:url('D:/Desktop/Background-Images/coneeu.jpg');
  background-position: 0 0px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.newengland{
  width:3840px; height:2160px; background:url('D:/Desktop/Background-Images/coneeu.jpg');
  background-position: 0 2160px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.europe{
  width:3840px; height:2160px; background:url('D:/Desktop/Background-Images/coneeu.jpg');
  background-position: 0 4320px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  font-family: Oswald;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#" class="co" onhover = "update()" >co</a>
    <a href="#" class="ne">ne</a>
    <a href="#" class="eu">eu</a>
    <a href="#" class="ab">ab</a>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Temp</h2>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Open</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason I had been dynamically importing it was because just while I was trying to learn what to do I found something that said you needed to have that there but I must have been misreading it. Thanks!